# WordPress Taxonomy Causing Pages to 404

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code to create a custom post type and a custom taxonomy associated with that post type:

```
register_post_type('deals', array(  
'label' => 'Deals',
'description' => '',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => "%make%", 'with_front' => false),
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' => 'deals',
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'menu_position' => 4,
'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes','sticky'),
'labels' => array (
    'name' => 'Deals',
      'singular_name' => 'Deal',
      'menu_name' => 'Deals',
      'all_items' => 'All Deals',
      'add_new' => 'Add Deal',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Deal',
      'edit' => 'Edit',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Deal',
      'new_item' => 'New Deal',
      'view' => 'View Deal',
      'view_item' => 'View Deal',
      'search_items' => 'Search Deals',
      'not_found' => 'No Deals Found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Deals Found in Trash',
      'parent' => 'Parent Deal',
),) );

$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Makes', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Make', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Makes' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Makes' ),
'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Make' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Make:' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Make' ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Update Make' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Make' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Make Name' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Make' ),
);  

register_taxonomy('make',array('deals'), array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'make' ),
'has_archive' => 'make'
 ));
```

And as you can see from the live site that works great: http://www.yourcardeals.co.uk/nissan-deals/

The issue I have is that it is causing regular pages to 404 i.e. http://www.yourcardeals.co.uk/manufacturers/

I have flushed Permalinks and do not have any pages or categories with the same name or slug as any taxonomies or custom post types.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: A good way of debugging that would be to see what `$wp_query` thinks about the page you're requesting. So in your 404 template(it should be `404.php`, or maybe it's in `index.php` - depends on your theme) do a `print_r($wp_query)` or `var_dump($wp_query)` - then look in the `query_vars` property. It will tell you how WordPress understood the current request. My thought is that since you don't use any prefix for your custom rewrite rules, WordPress thinks that it should display either a `deal` post, or a `make` term.

Comment: Thanks Nikola I have now changed the rewrite and everything works OK - seems I cant be as clever as I thought I could.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out :) Please add your solution as an answer and accept it - this way your question won't remain in the "unanswered" section :)