# WordPress post rewrite rule causes pages to 404

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I need my post permalinks to include a custom taxonomy value, `type`, like this:

`http://staging.mysite.com/article/post-title`

Where `article` is that post's `type` taxonomy value. I've gotten this to work, but the problem I'm running into is that now all of my site's pages are 404ing. My custom post type and normal post urls work as intended, it's just page urls that are broken. Here is the code that causes the issue with page urls:

```
// Type taxonomy (no issues here)
function create_type_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'type',
        'post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Type',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Type',
                'new_item_name' => 'New Type'
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'type',
                'with_front' => true
            ),
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_type_taxonomy', 0 );

add_action( 'init', 'st_default_post_type', 1 );

// Re-register built-in posts with a custom rewrite rule
function st_default_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'post', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public'  => true,
        '_builtin' => false, 
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%type%', 'with_front' => false ), // custom rewrite rule
        'query_var' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
    ) );
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'st_posts_permalink_structure', 10, 4);

// Replace custom rewrite rule on posts (%type%) with the taxonomy value
function st_posts_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample){
    if ($post->post_type != 'post') {
        var_dump($post->post_type);
        return $post_link;
    }
    else{
        if (strpos($post_link, '%type%') === FALSE){
            return $post_link;
        }

        $post = get_post($post);
        if (!$post){ 
            return $post_link;
        }

        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'type');

        if ( !is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]) ){
            $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        }
        else{
            $taxonomy_slug = 'type';
        }

        return str_replace('%type%', $taxonomy_slug, $post_link);
    }
}
```

Hoping another set of eyes might catch something that would cause page permalinks to 404. I've already tried just changing the permalinks setting in the admin to be `/%type%/%postname%/`, but this has the same issue. I found a couple other questions here that looked like the same issue I have, but none of them were answered:

[WordPress Taxonomy Causing Pages to 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645721/wordpress-taxonomy-causing-pages-to-404)

[When I add custom post type permalink rewrite, my regular post permalinks stop working. Can't get both to work at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378784/when-i-add-custom-post-type-permalink-rewrite-my-regular-post-permalinks-stop-w)

Comment: 5 years later and having the same exact issue ...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know this is a late answer, I had this issue today and found this info:

https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/taxonomy-slug-in-post-type-url.html

Credit goes to: Misha Rudrastyh for this answer obviously, he has not used the rewrite declaration in his cpt instead seems to use filters to do the same thing, this got me past all my posts and pages 404ing.

To quote his code for posterity, he explained to use this code to solve the issue:

```
function rudr_post_type_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {

    $post_type_name = 'post_type_name'; // post type name, you can find it in admin area or in register_post_type() function
    $post_type_slug = 'post_type_name'; // the part of your product URLs, not always matches with the post type name
    $tax_name = 'custom_taxonomy_name'; // the product categories taxonomy name

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( strpos( $permalink, $post_type_slug ) === FALSE || $post->post_type != $post_type_name ) // do not make changes if the post has different type or its URL doesn't contain the given post type slug
        return $permalink;

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $tax_name ); // get all terms (product categories) of this post (product)

    if ( !is_wp_error( $terms ) && !empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) ) // rewrite only if this product has categories
        $permalink = str_replace( $post_type_slug, $terms[0]->slug, $permalink );

    return $permalink;
}


add_filter('request', 'rudr_post_type_request', 1, 1 );

function rudr_post_type_request( $query ){
    global $wpdb;

    $post_type_name = 'post_type_name'; // specify your own here
    $tax_name = 'custom_taxonomy_name'; // and here

    $slug = $query['attachment']; // when we change the post type link, WordPress thinks that these are attachment pages

    // get the post with the given type and slug from the database
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var(
        "
        SELECT ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_name = '$slug'
        AND post_type = '$post_type_name'
        "
    );

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $tax_name ); // our post should have the terms


    if( isset( $slug ) && $post_id && !is_wp_error( $terms ) && !empty( $terms ) ) : // change the query

        unset( $query['attachment'] );
        $query[$post_type_name] = $slug;
        $query['post_type'] = $post_type_name;
        $query['name'] = $slug;

    endif;

    return $query;
}
```

In addition like I said you will not need to declare the "rewrite" portion in the CPT arguments, you can leave the filters to handle that "after the fact" type thing.